# Android L lock screen notification icon doesn't have gray circle background

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

When a push notification is sent to my application on Android L, the notification icon displayed with the notification in the lock screen doesn't have a gray circle for the background.  Other 3rd party apps (like Facebook) and Google apps have the gray circle for the background.  I've set the targetSdkVersion to 21 for my app, but doesn't make a difference.  I assume I don't have to manually create an image with a gray circle, right?  What needs to be done to make it display like the others?

Here's the code to build the notification:

```
        public Notification buildNotification(String alert,
                Map<String, String> extras) {
            Notification notification = super.buildNotification(alert,
                    extras);

            notification.icon = R.drawable.notification_ind;
            notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(
                        android.R.id.icon, R.drawable.notification_ind);                    

            return notification;
        }
```

Comment: What does it look like? What code generates the notification?

Comment: Added the code to the question.  It just shows the notification icon included with my app (an all white image with transparent background).  On the light gray background of the notification it's very hard to see and when you tap the notification it turns white so then it's impossible to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are indeed using Urban Airship Android Library for push notifications (as your code implies), you should instead override [getSmallIconId()](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/android/latest/reference/com/urbanairship/push/notifications/DefaultNotificationFactory.html#getSmallIconId()):

```
public int getSmallIconId() {
  return R.drawable.notification_ind;
}
```

And remove your code in `buildNotification()`. This ensures that the system formats the icon appropriately for all API levels.

Comment: That was right on the money.  I noticed a formatting problem on Gingerbread devices too (notification center shows a black background).  However, this approach doesn't seem to fix that.  I still have to have two different icons.  One with a black background for ICS and below and one with a transparent background for above.  Any ideas there?

Comment: The notification guidelines changed in Honeycomb - you can use a tool like the [Notification Icon Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html) to upload your existing icon (make sure to upload the largest one you have) and get a Gingerbread styled icon.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the colors from the icon and you will get a gray circle background

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html

> Update or remove assets that involve color in notification icon. The system ignores all non-alpha channels in action icons and in the main notification icon. You should assume that these icons will be alpha-only. The system draws notification icons in white and action icons in dark gray.